# change font compile path in webpack mix laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

i'm using laravel mix and i want compile my fonts. My fonts are compiled but their names are read from root. See my code at the bottom.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('../fonts/product-fonts/icomoon.eot');
  src:  url('../fonts/product-fonts/icomoon.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/product-fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/product-fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/product-fonts/icomoon.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

this is my sass code and Eventually The compilation will be as follows :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url(/fonts/icomoon.eot?c2f80bad46e9a20b6278361015fef1cd);
  src: url(/fonts/icomoon.eot?c2f80bad46e9a20b6278361015fef1cd) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/fonts/icomoon.ttf?5fa3cdef859a193e0f02c75fbd91d73a) format("truetype"), url(/fonts/icomoon.woff?96c27a3f7e16f9927cc8a0d2818c4e8e) format("woff"), url(/fonts/icomoon.svg?6e4d8f919ddb5d210c8807eb99149359) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

But I want to compile the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url(../fonts/icomoon.eot?c2f80bad46e9a20b6278361015fef1cd);
  src: url(../fonts/icomoon.eot?c2f80bad46e9a20b6278361015fef1cd) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/icomoon.ttf?5fa3cdef859a193e0f02c75fbd91d73a) format("truetype"), url(../fonts/icomoon.woff?96c27a3f7e16f9927cc8a0d2818c4e8e) format("woff"), url(../fonts/icomoon.svg?6e4d8f919ddb5d210c8807eb99149359) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Because my css file is in another folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with setting resource root

mix.setResourceRoot('../');

this is worked fine for me :)